# Crystal reports: remove empty space above text

Tags: crystal-reports

Recently I've been asked to bring dozens of weird-looking reports to one standard. All is fine, but there is one problem that shows up quite often and starts to annoy me:

http://img845.imageshack.us/img845/1549/fitsection.png

As you can see there is lots of empty space above the text "VESSEL" that I would like to get rid of and by default Crystal Reports has option to "fit section" only if the empty space is below the last line. Even worse, if the content of the section is made from combination of objects (i.e. text and lines, boxes etc) selecting all and dragging it up quite often messes up the alignment of items. While I can do it manualy it can be VERY annoying when has to be repeated on many reports. Is there any simple workaround?

EDIT: SOLVED
OK, I solved my problem. Just let me be clear once again what was the issue: Hrere is the original complicated header:
[image: http://img651.imageshack.us/img651/4299/move1.png]

After simply moving it it looks like this:
[image]

To fix it, before starting moving anything, Right click on the section and select "Remove all horizontal guidelines". Works like a charm:

[image]
Now I can easily select "Fit section" to remove empty space.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much to help you , but instead of moving fields you could move the guide lines. (that will make all the aligned field moved together with it)

Another thing would be:
On Crystal XI , you can also , click on the vertical ruler, then drag it to the left to create a new section, this will split an empty section at the top and field in a small section at the bottom
(would be best with pictures but not allowed)
you can then remove the upper section in the section expert

Comment: +1 I did not know you could split a section like that. Thanks for the info! OP can accomplish what they're trying to do in 3 quick clicks this way.

Answer (score 0):

Drag the "Vessel" to the top of the Page Header.  And then drag the dividing line up under "Vessel".

Comment: Yes, this is obvious solution but like I've said before in case of more complicated content (lines, boxes and text) it leads to loss of alignment.
Oh well, I guess there is no quick way :(